# Does a suspended user still gain or lose rep for votes cast on their Q&As while they are suspended, after the suspension ends?

Tags: discussion, reputation, account-suspension

A curious thought came to me while browsing the Stack today.

A suspended user has their reputation locked at 1 and doesn't gain or lose any rep *while* suspended. I.e. regardless of how many votes—up or down—are cast on the user's questions or answers, their rep doesn't change from 1.

But what about after the suspension ends?

Do all the votes get added up and the user gains or loses the total amount of rep they would have done if they weren't suspended or does the suspension block any rep from being gained during that period?

I checked the rpg Stack meta and couldn't seem to find an answer nor is their anything about it in the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since account suspensions aren't a Role-playing-Games-Stack-Exchange exclusive feature the answer can be found on [this Meta Stack Exchange question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125268), along with a full explanation of what a suspension means.

To quote the relevant section to answer this question:

> #### At the end of the suspension period
>
> The effects of a suspension are reversed by an hourly scheduled task. Therefore, once the suspension ends, it may take up to one hour for the effects to wear off; keep that in mind before filing a bug. Once that happens:
>
> - Earned reputation points (rep) are reinstated. This may be different from the rep value at the start of the suspension because your posts may have been upvoted, downvoted or deleted during the suspension period, and some of your votes may have been invalidated.

The suspension banner on a user's account page also kind of contains the answer in a bit less detail by linking to the Stack Overflow blog post "[A Day in the Penalty Box](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/)":

> At the end of this timed suspension period, your reputation will be recalculated, and your account will resume as normal.